# Let $(X, \|.\|)$ be an NLS, $x\in X$ and $0 < r<s.$ Show that $B(x, r)\subsetneq B (x, s).$

Tags: normed-spaces

In my text I've found the problem:

> Let $(X, \|.\|)$ be an normed linear space, $x\in X$ and $0 < r<s.$ Show that $B(x, r)\subsetneq B (x, s).$

I can see if $\exists~y\in X-\{0\}$ then $x+\frac{r}{\|y\|}y\in B(x,s)-B(x,r).$

But what if no such nonzero $y$ exists ? i.e. what if $X$ is the trivial vector space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C?$

Comment: Is NLS a normed linear space?

Comment: @LordSoth: yes..

Comment: If it is a trivial vector space, the theorem isn't true, obviously, since all balls around $x=0$ are the same. Probably an oversight in the problem, or maybe you missed some definition that insists that there are non-zero elements of $X$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the standard definition of normed linear space allows $X = \{0\}$, since this case might come up in applications, viz. as the kernel of some injective operator or the image of 
an operator which has zero as an eigenvalue.  So I think we need to assume $X \ne \{0\}$, or
(equivalently) that $X$ contains a non-zero element.  (Incidentally, the widipedia definition of NLS allows $X = \{0\}$, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space.)
Assuming this to be the case, the OP's argument appears to be basically correct.  Just for the record, here's my way of getting at it:  pick any $y \in X$, $y \ne 0$, so that $||y|| \ne 0$  Pick $\alpha$ real, $0 < \alpha <\frac{r}{||y||}$; then $||\alpha y|| = \alpha ||y|| < r$, so $\alpha y \in B(0, r)$.  Pick real $\rho$ with $r < \rho < s$.  Set $\beta = \frac{\rho}{||\alpha y||}$.  Then $||\beta \alpha y|| = \beta ||\alpha y|| = \rho$, so $\beta \alpha y \in B(0, s)$; since $\rho > r$, $||\beta \alpha y|| \notin B(0, r)$.  Now just translate everything by $x$.  Incidentally, this "proof" works whether the balls $B(x, d)$ are open or closed.

Comment: Can we conclude from the above result that, $\mathbb Q$ is not a normed linear space since $B(0,\sqrt 2)=B[0,\sqrt 2]?$